# Clarification in method of applying Poincare-Bendixson Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-system, periodic-functions

So I have these two equations:

$\ dx /dt = y-x^3+x$

$\ dy /dt = -x-y^3+y$

I'm trying to show the system has at least one periodic solution between:

$\ x^2+y^2 = 1$

$\ x^2+y^2 = 2$

I set $\ V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$  and find that $\ dV /dt > 0$ when $\ x^2+y^2 < 1$

My question is: **Why does this** ($\ dV /dt > 0$) **tell me that trajectories starting inside the region $\ x^2+y^2 < 1$ leave the region enclosed by $\ x^2+y^2 = 1$?**

Comment: First:  Bendixson.  Second:  you mean presumably "periodic solution".  A hint: what is the meaning of $dV/dt$ in general?

Comment: @user539887 The change in V w.r.t t will be positive. But I can't figure out what this tells me about the 'trajectories' on an x-y graph. (Re: second) As far as I know the theorem states that there will be a periodic solution yes (provided the above holds true) but that is not my question.

Comment: But it is connected with your question.  You know that $x^2+y^2$ increases along the solution as long as the solution remains in the region $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 < 1\}$.  Can there exist a periodic solution such that its image (that is, periodic orbit) has a nonempty intersection with $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 < 1\}$?

Comment: @user539887 I think the answer to your question is no, according to the theorem. The periodic solution will lie between the two limits, without crossing either.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  But formally proving it appears not so easy: if $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ then $dV/dt = 2 x^2 y^2 > 0$ everywhere except four points: $(\pm 1, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1)$.

Comment: @user539887 If I may ask; why would the rate of change of $\ V(x,y)=x^2+y^2 $ with respect to t have any effect on how it is plotted on an x-y graph?

Comment: If you take a point $(x, y)$ with $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 < 1$, the field vector at that point (that is, the vector tangent to the trajectory passing through the point) need not be perpendicular to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, however must point outside the circle.  In other words, trajectories are winding outside (clockwise, I think).

Answer (score 1):

Nite that  on the circle, $x^2+y^2=1$

$$ \frac {dV}{dt}= 4x^2y^2 $$ which is positive except at $(\pm 1,0)$ or $(0,\pm 1)$.

We can check the slopes at these points and conclude that the trajectory leaves the circle at these points as well.

for example at $(1,0)$, we have $ \frac{dx}{dt} = 0, \frac{dy}{dt} = -1$.

Thus  the trajectory is moving out the circle vertically downward.

Similarly for the other three points.